# How to close an activity at launch in Android

Tags: java, android, database, android-activity

In my app I have two activities. At the time of launch I am showing an edit text box and a button in the first activity. When the button is clicked, it moves to the next activity.

Before that, when the edit box is typed, it gets stored in a database. When the activity gets started it checks over the database. If the database is empty it shows the first activity else if the database is filled I want to show the second activity directly. But it is not happening in my code. Please anyone help me?  I want to know where I am going wrong…

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    db = openOrCreateDatabase("TestData.db", SQLiteDatabase.CREATE_IF_NECESSARY, null);
    db.setVersion(1);
    db.setLocale(Locale.getDefault());
    db.setLockingEnabled(true);
    final String CREATE_TABLE_COUNTRIES ="CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tbl_countries (id TEXT);";
    db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_COUNTRIES);
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put("id", textvalue );
    Cursor cx = db.rawQuery("select id from tbl_countries"  , null);
    counter=0;
    if (cx != null ) 
    {
        if  (cx.moveToFirst()) 
        {
            do 
            {
                counter=counter+1;
            }
            while (cx.moveToNext());
        }
    }                             
    db.close();         

    if(counter == 0)
    {
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        et = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);

        textvalue = et.getText().toString();
        b = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1); 
        b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
        {   
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) 
            {
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), SeconDClass.class);
                startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
                finish();
            }
        });
    }
    else if(counter>=1)
    {
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), SeconDClass.class);
        startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
        finish();             
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it might be because of this

```
 startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
        finish();
```

It doesn't make sense to finish the activity that would be receiving the result.

try just `startActivity()`, you don't really need to call `finish()` the first one.

Comment: You don't *need* to, but you may want to. It depends on what you want to happen when the use presses the back button once they are in the second activity. If you don't call finish() in the first then it will go back to that one. If you do call finish() then it will go back to whatever was happening before you entered this app.